# Separate accounts for PyPI and TestPyPI

Tags: python, package, pypi, account, testpypi

I have troubles to upload my package to TestPyPI to PyPI.

Here's the error:

> HTTPError: 403 Client Error: The user 'DeepAb' isn't allowed to upload to project 'deco'. See
> https://pypi.org/help/#project-name for more information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

I have separate accounts for each TestPyPI and PyPI and the credentials were given correctly.

Do I need to make separate accounts in PyPI and TestPyPI to upload the same package in both?

Answer (score 3):

**1.**

> I'm having troubles uploading my package from testpypi to PyPi
>
> `The user 'DeepAb' isn't allowed to upload to project 'deco'.`

Seems like there is already a project with that name (*deco*) registered on *PyPI*:

- https://pypi.org/project/deco/

Also read the link from the error message you posted:

- https://pypi.org/help/#project-name

**2.**

> Do I need to make seperate accounts in PyPi and TestPyPi for uploading same package in both?

Yes.

- *Because TestPyPI has a separate database from the live PyPI, you’ll need a separate user account for specifically for TestPyPI*

  - https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/
- *Register an account on https://pypi.org - note that these are two separate servers and the login details from the test server are not shared with the main server.*

  - https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#next-steps
- *In both cases, remember that PyPI and TestPyPI each require you to create an account, so your credentials may be different.*

  - https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth

Answer (score 0):

For [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) and [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/), you need to create each account and upload the same package because they are run on two separate servers so they don't share data.

The doc says below in [Next steps](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#next-steps):

> - ... - note that these are two separate servers and the login details from the test server are not shared with the main server.